# How to increase humidity indoors

Tags: home, temperature, winter, air

I would like to increase the humidity of my room. The room is heated with a hot water radiator pipe: hot water flows through the pipe that runs along the walls. I cannot control the temperature of the water (the pipe feels warm, but not hot at all) and can only control the volume of water that runs through the pipe (I have a scale from 1-10). The pipe is 1.5 inches wide. Humidity is low in the winter.

How can I increase the humidity of my room given these conditions?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's time to **invest in a good humidifier** (buy/rent)?

[image: indoor humidifier]

Maybe a bit smaller, but you've got the idea:)

If you want to pass that one, maybe it's time to wash your clothes and set up a drying rack in your room and **lay out damp clothing to dry overnight**. You'll save energy by not running the dryer, but adding more moisture to the air, all while adding the fresh scent of laundry to your room. Or you may decorate your room with **bowls of water** (place a few around your house and the water will evaporate into the dry air). Also don't forget to drink a lot of water.

See:

- [How To Add Moisture to the Air Without a Humidifier](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/how-to-add-moisture-to-the-air-107447)
- [Makeshift DIY Humidifier](http://fuckyeahlifehacks.tumblr.com/post/35710719659/makeshift-diy-humidifier)

Answer (score 3):

If it is possible you can place a pan of water on the radiator. A friend of mine did this and also added a little potpourri to the water and it made the room smell nice, as well as added to the humidity. Use and old pan, a lot of water scale tends to build up over the course of a winter season. This  also works well with wood stoves.

Comment: There's actually a market for this. placing a pan is more a temporary solution. I have already seen a radiator humidifier in a cabin in the mountains which looks pretty much like this one: http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/-we-dont-know-about-70034
So @user44816, you may want to check your local store for something like that.

Comment: @Alex nice, I had never seen that, my friend was using one of those plug in oil radiators And I had used the pan of water with my wood stove.